# A CSV file uploaded in a blob when sent the link of the file in Mail , is it downloadable on click?

Tags: java, azure, csv, gmail

My company sends a csv file to the users by uploading it to a storage service (azure) and the link of the file is shared in email , when the link is clicked a new tab opens and closes instantly , the file doesn't get downloaded . When the the link is copied and pasted in a new tab the file gets downloaded , what might be causing this issue . Thanks in Advance

the link is copied and pasted in a new tab the file gets downloaded but not when its clicked directly

Comment: Update : This issue is only caused in chrome , when the same thing is done in Firefox it's behaving as expected

Answer (score 0):

After reproducing issue from my side your getting error because of pop up enable/disable setting in your chrome.
Based on your requirement sample csv file is uploaded in azure blob storage and added the attachment in send email action  as shown in below images.
[image]

[image]
[image]
By following this document, you can enable or disable [pop up](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/guides/popups/chrome#:%7E:text=If%20you%20select%20Sites%20can%20send%20pop-ups%20and,option%20of%20allowing%20them%20on%20a%20case-by-case%20basis.) setting.

Go to settings>>privacy and security>>site settings>>Pop-ups and redirects>>Sites can send pop-ups and use redirects/Don't allow sites to send pop-ups or use redirects.

By checking your browser settings, you may be able to resolve the issue. If the issue persists, then contacting Azure support may be necessary.